# How can I set a title for a panel in a java form?

Tags: java, jpanel, title

I have created a JFrame and I want to add a panel appearing when I select an item in my selection list or when I write its name in a textbox....how can I set its title? should I add a label or it has a property as its title?!!!

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `JPanel` doesn't have a title.

Comment: It does it if you set the `border` property to `TitledBorder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the TitleBorder for the panel....

```
BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED),"Title");
```

Thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add a JLabel to the new panel and set the text 
in the ListSelectionListener or DocumentListener event handlers for the JList or JTextField components respectively.

Comment: TNX, But I want to set title for my panel not frame...a group of items in a panel with a specific title!!!!

Comment: OK,...but please let me know why I should add it to the ListSelectionListener?!! no event is going to happen due to this label!!!!

Comment: I was assuming you meant JList, perhaps you meant a list of radio buttons. Just add a listener to the textfield in that case.